# Ruby on rails - order term for event using AJAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

On my 'event#show' page I have button where user can purchase certain term for the event. Under that I have list of @term objects (each have :event_id, :datetime, :max_capacity). When user purchases the event, he's actually purchasing the @term. I'm displaying it using following code:

```
        <div class="list-group">
            <% @terms.each_with_index do |term, i| %>
                 <% if i == 0 %>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">
                <% else %>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                <% end %>
                        <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Starts in <%= distance_of_time_in_words(Time.now, term.date_on)  %></h4>
                        <p class="list-group-item-text">Maximum capacity: <%= term.maximum_capacity %></p>
                        <p class="list-group-item-text">Date: <%= term.date_on %></p>
                    </a>
            <% end %>
        </div>
```

This is how it looks like:

[image]

In my event.rb I have (it will be refactored):

```
def seats
    ["1", "2", "3"]
end
def total_price
    if self.seleced_seats == "1"
        self.price
    elsif self.seleced_seats == "2"
        self.price + self.price
    elsif self.seleced_seats == "3"
        self.price + self.price + self.price
    else
        self.price
    end
end
```

In my events_controller.rb I have:

```
  def price
    @event.seleced_seats = params[:edition]
    respond_to do |format|
        format.json {render json: @event, methods: [:total_price], only: []}
    end
  end
```

In price_calculation.js I have:

```
$(function() {
    $("#event_seleced_seats").change(function(){
        var seleced_seats = $(this).val();  

        jQuery.getJSON(window.location.href + "/price", {edition: seleced_seats}, function(data) {
            $("#price").text(data.total_price);
            console.log(data.total_price);

        });
    });
});
```

What I want is:

1. When user clicks on non-active "list-group-item" I want to select it (without reloading the page)
2. Then I need to re-draw collection under "How many seats" based on free seats
3. When user clicks "Purchase" I need to know which @term object is "active".

What approach would you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your link tag I would add 
`data-term-id=<%= term.id %>`

as an on click event just add an active class like this:

```
$(".list-group-item").on('click', function(){
  $(".list-group-item").removeClass('active')
  $(this).addClass('active')
})
```

and when purchase is clicked you can find and `active` element with it's id